# JQuery DATE RANGE: How to trigger an init "selection" event to set default values

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, range

This appears to be a fudamental omission from the JQ_ui Datepicker but maybe somebod has an answer.

I have need for **two inputs each with its datepicker display** when clicked / focused.

Each input result is associated with the other BUT HOWEVER the second is not a mandatory date input.

When using the **JQ_ui DATE RANGE example code** (*below*) all appears to work really well. I can even add many options to dress it all up a bit.

Therefore doing so whichever input is filled with a picker selected date it signals / prepares the other datepicker (*when it appears if focused*) to display limits on the dates available. That's exactly how it is expected and at that point a very useful widget.

**THEN comes the downer**. When the form page is redisplayed (*now or some future time*) the previous dates are to appear in the input boxes for reference / checking / correction.

By applying the saved values to the input boxes via 
$(function(){ $("#gmtTxt1").datepicker("setDate", '$Dst1'); etc
the above cross input functionality is lost UNTIL one of the date pickers is MANUALLY used to select another or reselect same date via a picker. Even hard coding embedding the saved defaults in the redisplayed form page stuffs it up.

So having explained in detail to avoid previous non-applicable answers does anyone know how to call, during initialization, a selection event to **embed default date(s) mimicking a manual selection process** and the cross widget interaction (*showing a pair of date pickers does NOT help either*).

FYI here is the JQ_UI Date Range example code (*minor element id changes*) on which I base my tests...

```
$(function() {
    var dates = $( "#first, #second" ).datepicker({
        //defaultDate: "+1w",   // n/a, many other options work ok to dress it up
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "first" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                selectedDate, instance.settings
            );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Set up a jsfiddle or link to the page?

Comment: jsfiddle SAMPLE... http://jsfiddle.net/qXpE5/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears the solution is quite straightforward.

From stuff I finally found on stackoverflow (*sigh; the hours searching*) I first put together the following...

```
$(document).ready(
    $(function(){
        var doDate;
        if($("#Text1").val()){
            doDate = new Date(Date.parse($("#Text1").datepicker('getDate')));
            $("#Text2").datepicker('option', 'minDate', doDate);
        }
        if($("#Text2").val()){
            doDate = new Date(Date.parse($("#Text2").datepicker('getDate')));
            $("#Text1").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', doDate);
        }
    })
);
```

...which seems to work just fine although if anybod discovers bugs in not-so-recent browsers and lets us all know it would be helpful; *I don't have those resources*.

**Placed in a named function** it can also be called using (***after***) a form reset (*onClick*) and a picker manual edit .change event (*which checks format and resets input if an error*).

This is a marvelous site with fantastic contributors. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to run at some time other than `onSelect`, then you'll need to tell this to the datepicker. Maybe you could hook into `create` as well?

```
$(function() {
    var formatDP = function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "first" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                selectedDate, instance.settings
            );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        };
    var dates = $( "#first, #second" ).datepicker({
        //defaultDate: "+1w",   // n/a, many other options work ok to dress it up
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        create: formatDP,
        onSelect: formatDP
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks **Sinetheta** but that just prepares the widget but still does not cause the current input value(s) to limit the picker(s) choices to them (*at start up*); as happens when a manual selection action is actually made via the picker. 

Logically the picker(s) should react and set up limits to any existing start-up input dates during init. I was just hoping some bod knew of a way of causing that to happen programmatically.